# Python create a list that contains tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out how to create tuples in a list. I looked at several different examples, they were slightly different.

```
first_names = ['Mark','Ashley','Ron']
points = ['10 points', '10 points', '20 points']

for i in range(len(first_names)):
#     print(first_names[i],points[i])
    scores = first_names[i],points[i]
    print(scores) # tuples
```

OUTPUT 1 of `print(scores)` shows:

```
('Mark', '10 points')
('Ashley', '10 points')
('Ron', '20 points')
```

Final Output, I am trying to convert this to a list of tuples like [(),(),()...()]. There are only 2 elements in each tuples.

```
[('Mark', '10 points'),
('Ashley', '10 points'),
('Ron', '20 points')]
```

Tried:

```
#     print([list(row) for row in scores]) # try 1 . splits into characters in the word in a list
#     level = map(list,scores) # try 2. splits into characters list within a list 
#     print(list(level))

#     scores = [first_names[i],points[i]] ##?? creates are list of the tuple
#     print(scores)
```

Comment: You're looking for `zip`

Comment: `print( [(x, y) for x, y in zip(first_names, points)] )` ?

Comment: `list(zip(first_names, points))`

Comment: you are just printing them -- store them in a data structure; create an empty list before your for loop, and then append your tuples to it. Or, you can use `zip` as suggested above.

Comment: @user3483203. Thanks for the reply. I did use the zip from your code. However I am getting multiple itirations of the data. Why does this happen? [('Mark', '10 points'), ('Ashley', '10 points'), ('Ron', '20 points')]
[('Mark', '10 points'), ('Ashley', '10 points'), ('Ron', '20 points')]
[('Mark', '10 points'), ('Ashley', '10 points'), ('Ron', '20 points')]

Comment: This is the output from the code I provided in my comment: `[('Mark', '10 points'), ('Ashley', '10 points'), ('Ron', '20 points')]`.  You probably ran it inside a loop.

Comment: @user3483203. I think I am looping through. If just use your code, with out for loop it is working. Thanks for the help!